# PicklingError when getting the result from ray

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ray

I'm working on slowly converting my very serialized text analysis engine to use Modin and Ray. Feels like I'm nearly there, however, I seem to have hit a stumbling block. My code looks like this:

```py
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
    analyzer=ngrams, encoding="ascii", stop_words="english", strip_accents="ascii"
)
tf_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(r_strings["name"])
r_vectorizer = ray.put(vectorizer)
r_tf_idf_matrix = ray.put(tf_idf_matrix)
n = 2
match_results = []
for fn in files["c.file"]:
    match_results.append(
        match_name.remote(fn, r_vectorizer, r_tf_idf_matrix, r_strings, n)
    )
match_returns = ray.get(match_results)
```

I'm following the guidance from the ["anti-patterns" section in the Ray documentation](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/ray-design-patterns/ray-get-loop.html), on what to avoid, and this is very similar to that of the "better" pattern.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alt.py", line 213, in <module>
    match_returns = ray.get(match_results)
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py", line 62, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1501, in get
    raise value.as_instanceof_cause()
ray.exceptions.RayTaskError(PicklingError): ray::match_name() (pid=23393, ip=192.168.1.173)
  File "python/ray/_raylet.pyx", line 564, in ray._raylet.execute_task
  File "python/ray/_raylet.pyx", line 565, in ray._raylet.execute_task
  File "python/ray/_raylet.pyx", line 1652, in ray._raylet.CoreWorker.store_task_outputs
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/serialization.py", line 327, in serialize
    return self._serialize_to_msgpack(value)
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/serialization.py", line 307, in _serialize_to_msgpack
    self._serialize_to_pickle5(metadata, python_objects)
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/serialization.py", line 267, in _serialize_to_pickle5
    raise e
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/serialization.py", line 264, in _serialize_to_pickle5
    value, protocol=5, buffer_callback=writer.buffer_callback)
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 73, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 580, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: args[0] from __newobj__ args has the wrong class
```

Definitely an unexpected result. I'm not sure where to go next with this and would appreciate help from folks who have more experience with Ray and Modin.

Comment: is it possible to share your full code?

Comment: `files` is a DataFrame of shape `(46542, 2)`. Is that helpful?

Comment: Just updated the code with a bit more; I didn't include the data cleaning steps. There's quite a bit of data cleaning with regex and string replacements. If I run this without `ray` and `modin` (with the obvs. code changes) it works fine, just takes a very. long. time.